# How to create a full background image

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to practice my css and I've been struggling with this for a while.

I'm trying to create a full background image for presentation with some text centered on it. But it (the image) doesn't cover the entire screen, instead it's bigger.

This is what I've got:

My App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import background from './images/background.jpg';
import './App.css';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={background} className="App-background-header"/>
          <div className="App-header-text">
            <p>This text should be center on the image above.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>This is a sample text after the image...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

My App.css

```
.App-header {
  height: 100%;
}

.App-background-header {
  height: 100%;

  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.App-header-text {
  color: #444444;
  text-align: center;
}
```

My goal is basically do something like this:
https://mdbootstrap.com/previews/docs/latest/html/navigation/intro-color.html

And this is what I'm getting:
[image]

**-- EDIT: --**

I already managed to get it working, but I'm not sure if it's a good practice to do what I did.

This is how it turned out:

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="App-header">
          <div className="App-header-text">
            <p>This text should be center on the image above.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="App-divider"></div>
        <div>
          Just a random text here...
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

App.css:

```
.App-header {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;

  position: absolute;

  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url('./images/background.jpg');
}

.App-header-text {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  top: 50%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.App-divider {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

I don't know if it's a good idea to have that "App-divider" on there. It does the job, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your image is set as img element in html by this:  `<img src={background} className="App-background-header"/>` and not as css background, so all styling from css is not applying to that image.

Replace `.App-background-header` in your css with this:

```
.App-background-header img {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
} 

.App-header-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  with: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: -100px;
  margin-top: -100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Or you can put your image as background like so:

```
.App-background-header img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("your_path_to_image.jpg");
}
```

But you have to remove this line from your app.js `<img src={background} className="App-background-header"/>`

Comment: Yes, beat me to it, :)
try
.App-header {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(image source);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

Comment: @ShannonWhite: sorry :)

Comment: Lol, no problem!

Comment: @August Thank you for your help. I went with the second approach, setting the image as a background in a div, I already managed to get it working, but I don't know if that's the right way to do it (the way that I implemented). Can you please check on my edit? And again, thanks. :)

Comment: @RottenCheese I'm glad if I could help, thank you for selecting the reply as solution, one small thing in your updated version: switch position: relative and absolute, so .App-header should have position relative and .App-header-text should have position absolute.

Answer (score 0):

Because you used an image. Your image need to be a style of your `App-header`. You can perform this with css property `background-image: src(imagePath)`